# How to auto upper-case text for Editor/Entry in Xamarin Forms in iOS 11.4

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uppercase

In iOS version 11.2, I used this code to set auto upper-case text. It run OK.

**Xamarin.Forms:**

```
public static readonly BindableProperty HasAutoUpperCaseTextProperty =
         BindableProperty.Create(
             nameof(HasAutoUpperCaseText),
             typeof(bool),
             typeof(EditorExtend),
             false);
 
     public bool HasAutoUpperCaseText
     {
         get { return (bool)GetValue(HasAutoUpperCaseTextProperty); }
         set { SetValue(HasAutoUpperCaseTextProperty, value); }
     }
```

*In iOS Renderer:**

```
Control.AutocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.AllCharacters;
```

Problem:

After I upgraded OS version of iPAD to iOS 11.4, It run incorrectly.

Have you ever met this problem? How to fix it in iOS 11.4?

**Update:**

I found problem, Auto-Capitalization (Go to Setting -> General -> Keyboard) was disable. So the iPAD device need to enable item Auto-Capitalization to use upper-case characters.
[image]

Comment: You just want it to work with iOS or in both?

Comment: I used Xamarin.Forms. But this problem is iOS only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In iOS Renderer:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            var nativeTextField = (UITextField)Control;

            nativeTextField.EditingChanged += (object sender, EventArgs args) =>
            {
                nativeTextField.Text = nativeTextField.Text.ToUpper();
            };

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this solution. But when user is typing quickly, it will be miss some character. Moreover, If user is typing they will not able to use predict (suggest) words in top of the soft-keyboard.

Comment: i didn't find any issue typing fast. maybe its related to T9 inserts in such case you just need to find the appropriate event for this "paste" event, still keeping the code above.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS Platform :

```
 [assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(EntryCapitalizeKeyboard), "EntryCapitalizeKeyboard")]
namespace YourProject.Platform.iOS.Renderers
{
    [Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
    public class EntryCapitalizeKeyboard : PlatformEffect
    {
        private UITextAutocapitalizationType _old;

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            var editText = Control as UITextField;
            if (editText == null)
                return;

            _old = editText.AutocapitalizationType;
            editText.AutocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.AllCharacters;
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            var editText = Control as UITextField;
            if (editText == null)
                return;

            editText.AutocapitalizationType = _old;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else comes across this, adding Keyboard = "Chat" to your editor in XAML does this automatically. I think it works for all platforms too.
You can also try other keyboard options, depending on what you want.